# check if a folder exist in datalake using java

Tags: java, azure-data-lake

I want to check if a folder exist in the datalake. If exist create a file in it and If folder doesn't exist create folder and then create a file inside the folder

```
    File directory = new File("/Raw/TEST_1/test");
    System.out.println("check if directory exist");
    if (directory.exists() == false) {

        client.createDirectory("/Raw/TEST_1/test");

        System.out.println("Directory created.");

        OutputStream stream = client.createFile("/Raw/TEST_1/test/" + FuFileName, IfExists.OVERWRITE);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory exist.");
        OutputStream stream = client.createFile("/Raw/TEST_1/test" + FuFileName, IfExists.OVERWRITE);
    }

} catch (ADLException ex) {
    printExceptionDetails(ex);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.format(" Exception: %s%n Message: %s%n", ex.getClass().getName(), ex.getMessage());
}
```

every time directory.exists() gives me output false even if that folder exist if not giving directory.exists()output as true and not executing else statements

Answer (score 0):

If you are **using Java 7 or higher**, then it is recommended to use `java.nio` in order to access the file system.

This very simple example can tell you if a given path is existing and if it is a directory or something else:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path dirPath = Paths.get("/Raw/TEST_1/test");

    if (Files.exists(dirPath)) {
        System.out.println(dirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString() 
                + " exists on the file system");
        if (Files.isDirectory(dirPath)) {
            System.out.println(dirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString() 
                    + " is a directory");
        } else {
            System.err.println(dirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                    + " is not a directory");
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println(dirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                + " does not exist on the file system");
    }
}
```

Comment: @deHaar-what import files are required for this path

Comment: @sqldeveloper I have added the imports to my answer

Comment: @deHaar-getting error at paths and exist even after adding required import files

Comment: @sqldeveloper Are the imports working or do they give an error? What error is it?

Comment: getting error for this import  java.nio.file.Path; and error at paths,exists

Comment: @sqldeveloper The error message states you have imported two different `Path` classes: `java.nio.file.Path` and `javax.persistence.criteria.Path`, remove the one that is not from `java.nio` if you don't need it anywhere else in the class...

Comment: @deHaar-can you please tell me what does( Files.exists(dirPath))  mean

Comment: @sqldeveloper It checks if the file system object that is stored in the `Path dirPath` exists on the file system. It's like having a `String dir = "C:\myFolder\"` and then finding out if this folder is existing.

Comment: @deHaar- want to know because  Files.exists(dirPath)-- this is always false even though the folder exist with a file in it or if the folder does not exist

Comment: @sqldeveloper Hmm... that may only be cause by a wrong path or if the program should check the presence on a remote server's drive but checks the local file system. Drive letters may be ambiguous in such situations...

Comment: @deHaar- do you have any suggestions for this ?

Comment: @sqldeveloper not really... Check with other folders and files (both can be represented by a `java.nio.file.Path`. For more, I would have to see the full code and the environment, so too much for stackoverflow.

Comment: @deHaar-got the solution client.checkExists(path) this will check if the folder exist